# JQ to parse nested arrays

Tags: arrays, json, scope, nested, jq

I have an issue to get data from JSON:

```
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "operationName": "GetValue",
      "batch_size": "2",
      "orders": [
        {
          "clientId": "7836",
          "validation_time": {
            "place": "136",
            "execute": "5379"
          }
        },
        {
          "clientId": "7837",
          "validation_time": {
            "place": "145",
            "execute": "5401"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "operationName": "GetValue",
      "batch_size": "3",
      "orders": [
        {
          "clientId": "7838",
          "validation_time": {
            "place": "122",
            "execute": "5201"
          }
        },
        {
          "clientId": "7839",
          "validation_time": {
            "place": "122",
            "execute": "5201"
          }
        },
        {
          "clientId": "7840",
          "validation_time": {
            "place": "122",
            "execute": "5201"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As a result, I wanna get info per order including clientId as key, place_validation_time and execute_validation_time per order. I tried the following:

```
.operations[] | select(.operationName=="GetValue") | {key: .orders[].clientId, place_validation_time: .orders[].validation_time.place, execute_validation_time: .orders[].validation_time.execute, batch_size: .batch_size}
```

But it has an unexpected result for me, it combined all clientId with all variations of validation_time.place and validation_time.execute, so instead of 1 object per order I've got 4 (for batch_size=2) e.g.
Expected:

```
{
  "key": "7836",
  "place_validation_time": "136",
  "execute_validation_time": "5379",
  "batch_size": "2"
}
```

Actual I have:

```
{
  "key": "7836",
  "place_validation_time": "136",
  "execute_validation_time": "5379",
  "batch_size": "2"
}
{
  "key": "7836",
  "place_validation_time": "136",
  "execute_validation_time": "5401",
  "batch_size": "2"
}
{
  "key": "7836",
  "place_validation_time": "145",
  "execute_validation_time": "5379",
  "batch_size": "2"
}
{
  "key": "7836",
  "place_validation_time": "145",
  "execute_validation_time": "5401",
  "batch_size": "2"
}
```

Does anybody have ideas how to avoid it and get as a result 1 object per 1 order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cartesian-product behavior is the result of including `.orders[]` at multiple places inside the object-construction expression.  Hoist it instead.  Assuming you want to select objects with `.batch_size` equal to "2", you could write:

```
.operations[]
| select(.operationName=="GetValue")
| .batch_size as $batch_size
| select($batch_size == "2")
| .orders[]
| {key: .clientId,
   place_validation_time: .validation_time.place,
   execute_validation_time: .validation_time.execute,
   batch_size: $batch_size}
```

### Addendum

If you have other items of interest at the .batch_size level, you would probably want to use a filter more like this:

```
.operations[]
| select(.operationName=="GetValue")
| . as $it
| select($it.batch_size == "2")
| .orders[]
| {key: .clientId,
   place_validation_time: .validation_time.place,
   execute_validation_time: .validation_time.execute,
   batch_size: $it.batch_size}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try, and if there is a lot of measurements on batch_size level, how should I script it? "| .batch_size as $batch_size, .batch_size1 as $batch_size1 | " doesnt work

Comment: jq is based on pipelines, so you would write `.x as $x | .y as $y`; but there are probably better alternatives if you have more than two or three such variables. 
 E.g. use a JSON object. See the jq manual

Comment: actually, it's 3 of it and I was trying use pipe as well like `| .batch_size as $batch_size | .batch_size1 as $batch_size1 |` but it led to syntax err in my case `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD, expecting '|' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>,`

Comment: solved, I should never use `.` in a variable name, now it's obvious enough. @peak Thank you!